# I have freezing issues on my powerbook g4 16.04

Tags: lubuntu

Every time I try to boot into Lubuntu 16.04 it only ever gets to the lockscreen and then when I put in my password it just freezes. I have not been able to get farther than this and it frustrates me to no end. As far as I know people have in fact encountered this problem before but no guide has been made for my exact problem that I know of.

The powerbook g4 is running 9xxx radeon graphics if you needed to know.

Comment: By consecutively pressing `Ctrl + Alt + F1`, will it let you log in there?

Comment: I'm sorry I actually already found out that if you have a powerbook g4 your best bet is lubuntu 12.04. I was frustrated and was tested out older versions to see if they worked. After 4 DVD's the only one that worked legitimately was 12.04. It seems that newer versions while saying they have increased performance and still are compatible are really not. thanks for helping anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I have had 16.04 working but it was such a headache I, like you reverted to 12.04.

It is a know bug in the AMD driver and there are a few posts suggesting 'appends' to the yaboot.conf file. I however could never get these to work reliably.

S